# Angular 5 : how to $state.go?

Tags: angular

In angularJs we could do `this.$state.go('route', { key: value});` to redirect to another route and pass params to a state with `ui-router` package.
I can't find a way to install `ui-router` package for angular 5.
With angular 5 I tried use router.navigate :

```
          const myArray= [];
          //... pushing elments to my array

          let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: {
          key: JSON.stringify({...myArray})
        }
      };

      this.router.navigate(['route'], navigationExtras);
```

But `router.navigate` is passing params with GET method.

Do I have to use "NgRx" to do that ? I can't find a real example using NgRx, only increment/decrement' ones

---

I used a shared service like suggested by @J.S.

Comment: You cannot pass data within a routing process to another component in Angular 2+. What do you want to achieve?

You could use ngrx but adding this library to your project, just to solve your specific problem, would be overkill. You can also use a normal service to communicate between components.

Comment: I have datas in component A.
I want to redirect user to component B and pass the datas with, but not with router.navigate (datas should not be passed in url).  To do this, it seem UI-router was used in the angularJS version of the app (with the `$state.go` function). Thanks

Comment: Like I said it is not possible with angular2 anymore. The angular team decided that the router should not be able to transport data, only as params within the url. How interaction between components work is described here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Sorry I couldn't edit anymore. 
I though of `@input` and `@output`, but my components are not nested. Using ngRx is indeed overkill (and not so easy to understand), but what are the options ? shared service ? Thanks

Comment: Yes a shared service is what you need. If the components are part of the same module provide the service there, otherwise in app.module/core.module depends on how you structured your project.